# Android Volley - GET request con parametros y body

Tags: java, android, android-volley, volley

Estoy intentando hacer una petición GET con la librería volley (Android) la cuál tiene parámetros en su URL y un BODY de tipo JSON y al realizar la misma recibo el siguiente mensaje de error " The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header. The inferred media type (*) 'application/octet-stream' is not supported for this resource. ".
Al probarlo en Postman agregandole parametros (en la sección parametros) y un BODY(en la sección body) tildando en RAW y seleccionando JSON y pasandole la info en ese formato la solicitud funciona correctamente, pero si al body lo mando vacío postman da el mismo error que he mencionado arriba(*), lo que quiere decir es que no le estoy pasando nada en el body de mi solicitud en Android.

[image: Aquí un ejemplo de postman con el body vacío. (Mismo error que en android studio)]

Aquí les dejo mi código (Android):

```
public void getOrderRegister(Company company, Order order, @NonNull Response.Listener<List<Order>> onSuccess, @NonNull Response.ErrorListener onError) {

User user = app.loadCredentials();

Gson gson = Utils.getGson();
final String jsonOrder = gson.toJson(order);

HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("user", user.getUsername());
params.put("pass", user.getPassword());
params.put("url", company.getUrl());
params.put("db", company.getBD());

final String url = "www.example.com";


RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(app);

final String mRequestBody = jsonOrder.toString();

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.i("LOG_RESPONSE", response);
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e("LOG_RESPONSE_ERROR", error.toString());
    }
}) {
    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "application/json; text/utf_8";
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        return mRequestBody.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUrl() {

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(url);
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iterator = params.entrySet().iterator();
            int i = 1;
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, String> entry = iterator.next();
                if (i == 1) {
                    stringBuilder.append("?").append(entry.getKey()).append("=").append(entry.getValue());
                } else {
                    stringBuilder.append("&").append(entry.getKey()).append("=").append(entry.getValue());
                }
                iterator.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
                i++;
            }
            url = String.valueOf(stringBuilder);

        return url;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        String responseString = "";
        if (response != null) {
            responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
        }
        return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    }
};

requestQueue.add(stringRequest);}
```

Alguien puede ayudarme ? no logro mandar nada en el body de la request.

Comment: Por definición las peticiones GET no tienen cuerpo, todos los datos que quieras mandar en una petición GET deben viajar en la URL. Si quieres mandar body tienes que usar POST, no GET.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la info, definitivamente tuve que cambiar mi peticion GET a POST/PUT

Answer (score 0):

> Estoy intentando hacer una petición GET con la librería volley
> (Android) la cuál tiene parámetros en su URL y un BODY de tipo JSON

Si estas tratando de realizar una petición `GET` y estas enviando un BODY,  esto no es necesario y no tiene ningún significado al realizar esta petición, a diferencia de una petición `POST` que si requieres un BODY.

Tu petición GET debería tener esta forma y no deberías tratar de agregar un BODY a la misma:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(String respuesta) {
            //…
         }
      },
      new Response.ErrorListener() {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //…
         }
      }
);
```

donde el valor de la url define tambièn sus paràmetros, ejemplo:

> `http://www.stackoverflow.com/?param1=ga&param2=juan&nombre=Juan&apellido=Rey`